# NSScanner & Array Loops

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsscanner

I am trying to use NSScanner is an NSArray enumeration loop. This however fails:

> -[NSXMLElement length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x280da30

No, I am not calling `length` anywhere. It seems like the value of found gets changed before the scanner completes, hence making it blank, causing the `length` error.

If I remove the loop and hardcode the string (i don't want that, it's just a test) the code below works. (excluding the enumeration of course)

It never gets as far as calling the `NSLog`s either...

Here's my code:

```
    for (NSString*found in arr)
    {
        NSLog(@"Found %@",found);

        NSString*search = [NSString stringWithString:found];

        NSString *separatorString = @"\"";                             
        NSString *container = nil;
        NSScanner *aScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:search]; 

        [aScanner setScanLocation:0];                                        
        [aScanner scanUpToString:@"src=\"" intoString:nil];          
        [aScanner scanString:@"src=\"" intoString:nil];                     
        [aScanner scanUpToString:separatorString intoString:&container]; 

        NSLog(@"scanned");

        NSLog(@"%@",container);

        NSImage*previewImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[relativeDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:container]];

        [preview setImage:previewImage];

        [previewImage release];

        progressed = progressed + 1;

        [convertProgress setDoubleValue:[convertProgress doubleValue] + progressed];
    }
```

How can I get this to work?

Edit:

Here's the input:

```
    NSXMLDocument*doc = [[NSXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:webPath] options:NSXMLDocumentTidyHTML error:nil];

    NSArray*arr = [doc nodesForXPath:@"//img[@src]" error:nil];
```

Comment: It might help to know what the input looks like...

Comment: By the way, the scanning code works fine for simple inputs.

Comment: I've already said that it works fine for simple inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation:

> The `nodesForXPath:error:` method
>   returns an array of NSXMLNode objects

Your array is **not full of strings**.  It is full of various `NSXML*` objects.  They aren't garbage.  This is exactly how it is supposed to work.

You may not be calling `length`, but `stringWithString:` is probably calling `length` to figure out how much space to allocate in the new string.

---

Conversion to a string can mean a lot of things.   An XML node may be a standalone tag, it may be some inline CDATA, it may be a tag with various attributes.   As well, an XML document is highly structured.  It is rarely meaningful to walk through the contents of a document as a straight enumeration of tags/contents without applying some amount of structural meaning.

You are likely going to need to recurse or otherwise walk the tags and interpret their contents appropriately.

The first step would be to remove everything but that initial NSLog() and see what you got.  Then figure out how to walk the tree of nodes.  Then figure out how to parse 'em appropriately.

Comment: how can I convert it to a string?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your `arr` contains `NSString` objects? The fact that `NSXMLElement` is throwing an error looks fishy to me.

**Edit**

Yep, looks like the docs say the array from `nodesForXPath` doesn't contain `NSString` objects, but `NSXMLElement` objects.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLNode_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSXMLNode/nodesForXPath:error:

Comment: They are NSStrings. I have explained why it calls `NSXMLElement` in the log - its outputting garbage, it's happened a few times. As the loop moves on, it seems like the string its supposed to search is cleared...

Comment: I'm with Paul, in all likelihood some of the items in the array are not instances of NSString. How are you creating the array? (Code would be helpful).

Comment: They are strings. I've edited the post to show how I create the array.

Comment: According to Apple's docs: "The nodesForXPath:error: method returns an array of NSXMLNode objects".

Comment: I am certain that [doc nodesForXpath:] is not returning strings but NSXMLElement

Comment: Thanks -  how can I get the string value though?

Comment: Have you tried `XMLString`? (And BTW, saying that `stringValue` "doesn't work" is a little misleading.)